# Codeigniter and jQuery issue

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm working with chart.js to create graphics with a controller and a view:

The controller:

```
public function clickGraphic(){
    $home_data['click'] = $this->intranet_model->clickedFiles();
    $home  = $this->load->view('modules/Home/index', $home_data, true);
    return $home;
}
```

The view:

```
<div class="portlet-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <canvas id="filesChart" width="650" height="400"></canvas>               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I create the graphic:

```
$(function(){
    var barChartData = {
    labels : [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" ],
    datasets : [
            {
             fillColor : "rgba(11,103,158,0.5)",
             strokeColor : "rgba(11,103,158,1)",
             data : [7,5,4,3,3,3,2,2,2,1]
            }
        ]
    }
    var barChartData1 = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                    fillColor : "rgba(11,103,158,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(11,103,158,1)",
                    data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
            },
            {
                    fillColor : "rgba(255,245,0,0.5)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(255,245,0,1)",
                    data : [5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
            },
        ]
    }

    var myLine = new        Chart(document.getElementById("filesChart").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData);
    var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById("filesChart2").getContext("2d")).Bar(barChartData1);

});
```

At the first page load it works, but when I called the controller again from another view I loose the graphic. How can I maintain it?

```
<ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb">
    <li>
        <i class="icon-home"></i>
        <a href="/admin/clickGraphic/">Página Principal</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `I called the controller again` means you are calling via ajax?

Comment: Sorry, I improved the question.

Comment: Are you re-loading same page?

Comment: When I call the controller it generate the page again, and I loose the data, I think it happens because it only loads once when the document is ready, but not when I called again.

Comment: How is the data supplied? Is the javascript for Chart.js inserted at the end of the view? Are you calling the controller through the link in the last code block? If so, are you generating a whole new page or are you expecting the data to be inserted dynamically? It may help to post more than just little snippets of code so we can get a better idea of what's going on.